# How to make a drop down list which responds to the letter you enter?

Tags: html, xml, jsp

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>choose a country</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Where would you like to go?</h1>
  <form action="some.jsp">
    <select name="item">
      <option value="america">America</option>
      <option value="turkey">Turkey</option>
      <option value="brazil">France</option>
      <option value="spain">Spain</option>
      <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
      <option value="Dubai">Dubai</option>
      <option value=A rgentina ">Argentina </option>
        <option value = "canada "> Canada </option>
        <option value = "france ">France</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit " value="lets go!! ">
     </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I want to make a drop list in which when you press the letter A then all the countries with the letter A pop up. I'm confused on how to do this
also I want to align this to the centre of the page. How would I go about this.

Comment: I don't get what you want to do with the drop down, its a filter?

Comment: Try some autocomplete text which will help you .

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_autocomplete

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

To align the text on center of page, just add a class to form like this:

```
<form action="some.jsp" class="form">
```

And then add 'text-align:center' like This:

```
.form {
 text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: How this answer to this question?

Comment: " also I want to align this to the centre of the page. How would I go about this." this part of question?

Comment: You didn't answer to the main part

Comment: I add a comment because i didn't get the main part, if he wants a filter or something else...

Comment: Ok I will explain update the answer . OP wants something similar like Autocomplete text behaviour

Comment: yes yes I want something similar autocomplete behaviour I just phased it wrong in my question

Comment: @soorapadman added the w3schools link that i think can help you on the comment

Answer (score 0):

It's default behavior that if the options list is open and you press a letter, the first option with that pressed letter is focused.

Use have to use javascript if you want to sort / filter that list. Then I'd recommend using `<ul>` and `<li>` elements.

But here's a simple filtering of list with a css class. Does work well for a small amount of elements. If you have a lot of elements, consider using `Array.filter()` instead of `Array.map()` and `Element.classList`.

```
<body>
<style>
    .option--hidden {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<ul class="my-list">
    <li>AA</li>
    <li>AB</li>
    <li>AC</li>
    <li>BA</li>
    <li>BB</li>
    <li>BC</li>
    <li>CA</li>
    <li>CB</li>
    <li>CC</li>
</ul>
<script>
    //
    // I like to use an instance variable to store data in order to avoid unneccessary loading
    //
    instance = {
        options: [...document.querySelectorAll('.my-list li')],
    }

    function hideAllButSelected(pressedKey) {
        //
        //  Loop through options ans see if their first characters match the pressed key.
        //  If yes then leave it visible, otherwise hide them.
        //
        instance.options.map(option => {
            const optionText = option.innerText.toLowerCase();
            const optionFirstCharacter = optionText.charAt(0).toLowerCase();

            //  You can freely call classList.remove() because it gives no error even if classname doesn't exist.
            //  On every iteration remove the hidden -class to show all that are not in the scope of pressed key.
            option.classList.remove('option--hidden'); 
            if (pressedKey !== optionFirstCharacter) option.classList.add('option--hidden');
        });
    }

    function showAllOptions() {
        instance.options.map(option => {
            option.classList.remove('option--hidden');
        });
    }

    //  Pls use a handler function for events.
    function handleKeyPress(e) {
        const key = e.key;

        if (key === '§') {
            this.showAllOptions();
        } else {
            this.hideAllButSelected(key);
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener('keypress', e => this.handleKeyPress(e));
</script>
```